# How can I install windows 10 to two hard drives while enabling hibernation?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, hibernate

I would like to install Windows to two hard drives, lets call them HDD-1 and HDD-2.

If I boot HDD-1, I would like to put it into hibernation, and then boot into HDD-2.

However, if I put HDD-1 into hibernation, it immediately boots to HDD-1, and does not allow me to pick the other OS.

I would like to do this so I can "keep my work open" in HDD-1, and boot to HDD-2 and do whatever.

Basically what I am trying to do is have a "Work" installation of windows, and a "play" installation of windows. But having to close out all of my work in order to boot into my "play" installation is going to be very annoying. I like being able to leave things open to resume them the next day.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: When you install windows, the other drive should be disconnected, otherwise boot files for both are on one drive and may be the cause of this issue.. I suspect when you installed the 2nd W10 the other drive with W10 was connected?

Comment: @Moab, actually no. I removed HDD-1, installed W10 to HDD-2, removed HDD-2, installed W10 to HDD-1. Only shows HDD-1 in BIOS boot menu

Comment: Sort of figured this out. Made a small 10 gig partition and installed ubuntu there. GRUB allows me to boot to either Windows installation. Would like to get ride of Ubuntu now..